# How to make floating table of contents work using the loveit theme with blogdown

Tags: r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I'm building a blog with [dillonzq/loveit](https://github.com/dillonzq/LoveIt) theme in conjunction with R's [blogdown package](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown). The loveit theme has a really cool floating table of contents. It looks like this

[image]

and you can see an example of it in action [here](https://hugoloveit.com/theme-documentation-basics/). Unfortunately I can't get this to play nicely with .Rmd files rendered by blogdown. I can, however, get it to work with .md files.

## Minimal Reproducible Example

1. Set up a new site with the loveit theme

```
blogdown::new_site(theme = "dillonzq/LoveIt")
```

2. Make two very similar posts, where one is a `.Rmd` and the other a `.md`.

*content/posts/test_Rmd.Rmd*

```
---
title: "Test Rmd"
author: "John Johnson"
---

## Something cool
Here' something cool

### Details
Here are some details

## Something cooler
Here's something cooler
```

*content/posts/test_md.md*

```
---
title: "Test md"
author: "John Johnson"
---

## Something cool
Here' something cool

### Details
Here are some details

## Something cooler
Here's something cooler
```

3. Launch the site with `blogdown::serve_site()`, then compare *http://127.0.0.1:4797/test_md/* and *http://127.0.0.1:4797/test_rmd/*.

The `.md` version works (note the source code)
[image]
[image]

and the `.Rmd` version doesn't work.
[image]
[image]

## Attempted Solutions

I've tried setting

```
output:
  blogdown::html_page:
    toc: true
```

in the front matter of my .Rmd. This creates a table of contents, but not the pretty, floating toc as in the loveit theme. I've also tried tinkering with the toc related variables in config.toml but to no avail.

I see where the loveit theme generates a table of contents in the template [posts/single.html](https://github.com/dillonzq/LoveIt/blob/master/layouts/posts/single.html) but I don't understand why this doesn't play nicely with blogdown. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the problem comes from the HTML file created by the `.Rmd` file. There are two options to deal with this.

### 1) Keep the `.md` file

You can add the option `keep_md: true` in the YAML. Therefore, the file `test_rmd.Rmd` now looks like that:

```
---
title: "Test Rmd"
author: "John Johnson"
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
---
  
## Something cool
Here' something cool

### Details
Here are some details  

## Something cooler
Here's something cooler
```

However, `blogdown::serve_site()` does not actually compile the `.Rmd` file. Therefore, you need to knit it to generate the `.md` file **before** using `blogdown::serve_site()`. Apparently, for some reason that I don't understand, `.md` files have the priority when using `blogdown::serve_site()`, and the HTML file generated is therefore useless.

### 2) Replace `.Rmd` by `.Rmarkdown`

Again, for a reason that I don't understand, using `.Rmarkdown` extension instead of `.Rmd` solves the problem. However, these two extensions have different capacities, that are detailed [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/output-format.html).

Comment: I ended up re-building all my articles as `.Rmarkdown`, except for one which needed to build a .gif (which is incompatible with `.Rmarkdown`). Appreciate the answer but I'm going to leave this open to see if someone comes along with a better solution.